# Fix part of a variable during eager execution training in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is there a way to only update *some* of the variables during an eager execution update step? Consider this minimal working example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)

x = tf.Variable([1.0, 2.0])

def train(x):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        loss = x[0]**2 + x[1]**2 + 1/(x[0]+x[1])
        variables = [x]
        grads = tape.gradient(loss, variables)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, variables))

for _ in range(2000):
    train(x)
    print(x.numpy())
```

Which converges to `[0.5, 0.5]`. I'd like to fix the value of `x[0]` to it's initial value, while keeping everything else the way it is. What I've tried so far:

- Adding a `x[0].assign(1.0)` operation to the training step which grows the graph unnecessarily
- Changing `variables = [x[:-1]]` which gives `ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['tf.Tensor([1.], shape=(1,), dtype=float32)']`
- Adding `grads = [grads[0][1:]]` which gives `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: var and delta do not have the same shape[2] [1] [Op:ResourceApplyGradientDescent]`
- Doing both, which gives `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

For this MWE I can easily use two separate variables, but I'm interested in the generic case where I only want to update a known slice of an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the gradient of the index you don't want to update to 0. In the code snippet bellow, the `mask` tensor indicates which elements we want to update (values `1`), and which elements we don't want to update (values `0`).

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)

x = tf.Variable([1.0, 2.0])
mask = tf.constant([0.0, 1.0])

def train(x):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        loss = x[0]**2 + x[1]**2 + 1/(x[0]+x[1])
        variables = [x]

        grads = tape.gradient(loss, variables) * mask
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, variables))

for _ in range(100):
    train(x)
    print(x.numpy())
```

Another possible solution for your problem can be to stop the gradient on operations that `x[0]` is dependent on. For example:

```
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)

x = tf.Variable([1.0, 2.0])

def train(x):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        loss = tf.stop_gradient(x[0])**2 + x[1]**2 + 1/(tf.stop_gradient(x[0])+x[1])
        variables = [x]

        grads = tape.gradient(loss, variables)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, variables))

for _ in range(100):
    train(x)
    print(x.numpy())
```

Comment: This almost works. However part of the reason for masking is that some of my numbers become nans due to the gradient (namely the first and last entries due to boundary conditions). Multiplying a nan by 0 still gives it a nan.